# How to write a proper ES6 wrapper for something like sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, es6-class, proxy-pattern

Hello I am wondering how to write a proper wrapper for something like `sessionStorage`.

I could implement a class of my own and proxy through method invocation to the `sessionStorage`. For example with some quick pseudocode:

```
class customStorage {
    set(key, value) {
        sessionStorage.setItem(key, value);
    }
}
```

I would use it like so:

```
const customStorage = new customStorage();
customStorage.set('my-key', 'hello there');
```

All fine and dandy but I would like for a user to have the freedom to use other native `sessionStorage` methods on my proxy that I might not implement myself in my proxy.

for something like `sessionStorage` it would be do-able to write them all yourself even though all they might do is proxy through to `sessionStorage` without any intervention.

For something larger where I would only manipulate 5 methods out of 20 or something this does not seem viable.

Overwriting native functionality with prototype also seems like a deathtrap leading to many `wtfs-per-minute`.

So far what I have read from 'proxy patterns' in Javascript they all implemented all of the methods from the original Object. Am I forced to do this?

Is there some sort of way to create an ES6 class and set the prototype of that very class to sessionStorage in the constructor or something?

Comment: What do you mean by "*proper wrapper*"? What is the wrapper supposed to accomplish? Why would one use the wrapper instead of `sessionStorage` directly?

Comment: To modify the default functionality of some methods without having to implement all of them. For example if I perform a `set` or `get` since I am working with `JSON` objects 90% of the time I would like to do a `stringify` or `parse` to set or retrieve data. And with 'proper' I mean a clean approach preferably in ES6 since a lot of features like ES6 classes add a lot of readability to code.

Comment: Ah, you should've made that clear in the question.

Comment: English is not my native tongue and it is hard enough to describe something like this, I am trying though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like for a user to have the freedom to use other native `sessionStorage` methods on my proxy that I might not implement myself in my proxy.

I would rather give the user the freedom to just use the native `sessionStorage` *directly* if he intends to do that. Your implementation does have its own, separate functionality, which does use `sessionStorage` internally but is not the `sessionStorage`. There's no reason to implement its interface on your object. (See also [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)).

> Is there some sort of way to create an ES6 `class` and set the prototype of that very class to `sessionStorage` in the constructor or something?

No. Even when you want to implement that interface, your objects are not really `SessionStorage` instances. Also in this particular case, `sessionStorage` is a singleton and you cannot instantiate a second `SessionStorage`, so inheritance does absolutely not work here.

There are three ways around this (I'll write code for the generic case with instantiation from arbitrary objects to be wrapped, you likely want a static singleton-like one for your custom storage):

- Mixins to decorate the object. Don't create another instance, just overwrite the properties on the original. (This is likely out of the question for builtin objects)

  ```
  function custom(orig) {
      orig.get = function() { … };
      return orig;
  }
  ```
- Parasitical inheritance, creating a complete wrapper using reflection on the object.

  ```
  function custom(orig) {
      const obj = {
          get() { … };
      };
      for (const p in orig) { // assuming everything is enumerable - alternatively use
                              // for (const p of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(…))
                              // or even incorporating the prototype chain
          obj[p] = typeof orig[p] == "function"
            ? (...args) => orig[p](...args)
            : orig[p];
      }
      return obj;
  }
  ```
- A literal `Proxy` with a [suitable handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler):

  ```
  const customMethods = {
      get() { … }
  };
  const handler = {
      has(target, name) {
          return name in customMethods || name in target;
      },
      get(target, name) {
          if (name in customMethods) return customMethods[name];
          else return target[name];
          // if its a native object with methods that rely on `this`, you'll need to
          // return target[name].bind(target)
          // for function properties
      }
  }

  function custom(orig) {
      return new Proxy(orig, handler);
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I will try out the third one it seems to get really close to what I am looking for. Much appreciated!

Comment: Why do you need the `has` handler by the way? The example works fine without it and the `in` operator already checks the `customMethods` if it does not exist it simply proxies to the native object. This seems to work fine for me? https://jsfiddle.net/pouk8rya/

Comment: @Stephan-v The `has` handler will be called when the `in` operator is used on the proxy - it does matter if you have custom keys that are not in the original object. You'll want to check out the other proxy handlers to see whether there's anything you want a custom behaviour for, e.g. enumeration.